# Extract & store Strings with uneven spaces using AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file contain data like below. I want to cut first and last Columns and store in variables.  I am able to print it using command "`awk -F" {2,}" '{print $1,$NF}' filename.txt` " but I am unable to store it in variables using `awk -v` command.

The main problem is that first column contains space between words and `awk` is treating it 3 columns if I am using `awk -v` command.

Please suggest me how I can achieve this.

---

### XML                           2144          11270           2846        3385074

### Java                          7356         272651         242949        1350596

### C++                            671          46497          42702         179366

### C/C++ Header                   671          16932          57837          44248

### XSD                            216           3131            807          27634

### Korn Shell                     129           3686           4279          12431

### IDL                             90           1098              0           8697

### Perl                            17            717            795           5698

### Python                          37           1102            786           4640

### Ant                             62            596            154           4015

### XSLT                            18            117             13           2153

### make                            14            414           1659           1833

### Bourne Again Shell              32            532            469           1830

### JavaScript                      10            204             35           1160

### CSS                              5             95             45            735

### SKILL                            2             77              0            523

### HTML                            11             70             49            494

### SQL                              9             39             89             71

### C Shell                          3             13             25             31

### D                                1              5             15             10

### SUM:                         11498         359246         355554        5031239

Comment: Are you trying to use `awk -v 'foo=$1' ...` to set the variable based on the content of each line? That doesn't work. `-v` is meant to insert text that's known before awk is run. Also, the field separator is a regular expression, not a string. On gawk, it matches all whitespace, so the number of leading spaces makes no difference. If setting FS manually, `[ \t]+` is a reasonable whitespace separator. (It's easy to remember, and portable, but won't work with exotic strings like those containing unicode non-breaking space characters.)

Comment: Please show the code you tried, so we have a better idea what you're trying to do and what the problem is. And finally, which version of awk are you using?

Comment: Below is the code I am using to store it in variable.   cat loc.txt | while read line
        do
                           echo $line | awk -v Lang="$1"
                           echo "Language is=$Lang
        done

Comment: Also within the loop if I uses  awk -F" {2,}" '{ print $1,$NF }' then it correctly pick the first words as "Bourne Again Shell" Regardless of spaces between them but I am unable to store them in variables.

Answer (score 0):

The `-v VAR=value` parameter is evaluated before the awk code executes. It's not actually part of the code, so you can't reference fields because they don't exist yet. Instead, set the variable in code:

```
awk '{ Lang=$1; Last=$NF; print Lang, Last; }'
```

Also, setting those variables within awk won't affect bash's variables. Environments are hierarchical--each child environment inherits some state from the parent environment, but it never flows back upwards. The only way to get state from a child is for the child to print it in a format that the parent can handle. For example, you can pipe the above command to `while read LANG LAST; do ...; done` to read the awk output into variables.

It seems from your comment that you're trying to mix awk and shell in a way that doesn't quite make sense. So the correct full code (for getting the variables in a bash loop) would be:

```
cat loc.txt | awk '{ Lang=$1; Last=$NF; print Lang, Last; }' | while read LANG LAST; do ...; done
```

Or if it's a fixed number of fields, you can skip awk entirely:

```
cat loc.txt | while read LANG _ _ _ _ LAST; do ...; done
```

where the "_" just represents a variable which is created and ignored. It's a bit of a convention that underscores represent placeholders in some programming languages, and in this case it's actually a variable which could be printed with `echo $_`. You'd give it a real name, and name each field differently, if you cared about the middle values.

Neither of these solutions cares about how much whitespace there is. Awk doesn't care unless you tell it to, and neither does the shell.

Comment: Thanks Piojo for detailed explanation, i tried to executed what you have said above but unfortunately it is providing the required output   I have written something                                  cat loc.txt | awk '{ Lang=$1; Last=$NF; print Lang, Last; }' | while read Lang Last;
do
        echo "var1-$Lang & var2=$Last"
done  ------------------ It is showing output as var1-Bourne & var2=1830 and "Again shell " in var1 is missed. but I was expecting output as var1=Bourne Again Shell & var2=1830.

Comment: Oh, the fields have spaces _within_ them? That's going to confuse both awk and bash. Assuming you have already gotten awk to correctly parse the fields, you can print each on a separate line for bash to read in one whole variable per line: `awk '{ Lang=$1; Last=$NF; print Lang; print Last; }' | while read LANG; do read LINE; ...; done;`

Comment: In the above, each `read` statement will consume one line from the input stream, and as long as your lines are always printed in pairs, it will work. More sophisticated programs print a NULL byte instead of a newline to separate different pieces of data, but I'm not comfortable enough with awk and bash to help with that. Awk and bash are rather limited compared to general purpose languages like perl.

Comment: @AjayKashyap Note: if I helped, the way to acknowledge that and point it out to others is to click the "up" icon next to my answer (if I helped you understand something), or to click the check mark if what I said is what you'd consider the "correct" answer to the question you asked.